# How can I write a VSCode extension that selects the type of file I am writing in based on my own commands?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, file-extension

So whenever I create a new react project with `npx create-react-app` or add a new file to the existing `src` folder the convention is to have the name of the file capitalized + the `.js` file extension.

If I look at the status bar in VSCode at the bottom of the screen I can see that the selected language is javascript, vanilla javascript. With vanilla javascript all my css, html and react extensions are not working so I have to manually click on it everytime and select javascript react(.jsx) for them to work properly.

I want to write an extension as that would also be a lovely project that works as the following: if a .js file is starting with a capital letter(as in `App.js`, `Todos.js` or `Todo.js` the selected language is automatically react.

[You can see in the status bar that VSCode does not recognize react files as being react files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m6bm.png)

I tried looking at the documentation how may I do that but found nothing useful as most of the tutorials are found are not working with VSCode itself but rather implementing stuff from outside to inside VSCode. I have the development workspace set up but I can't find any reference as to how can I do something like that and would need some help.

Comment: and you're not naming your files with ".jsx" because... why?

Comment: Because it's exactly doing the same thing? I said that with npx create-react-app the files generated are .js

Comment: did you know about VS Code's "file associations" setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @starball suggested a "file association" can do what you want.  In your `settings.json` (or workspace or folder settings):

```json
  "files.associations": {
    "^[A-Z]*.js": "javascriptreact"
  }
```

---

If you want to see one way an extension could do this try this code:

```js
vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(async editor => {
  if (editor) {
    if (editor.document?.languageId === "javascript") {
      const baseName = URI.Utils.basename(editor.document.uri);  // import or require 'vscode-uri'
      const extName = URI.Utils.extname(editor.document.uri);    // import or require 'vscode-uri'

      if (baseName.match(/^[A-Z]/) && extName === '.js') {
        await vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage(editor.document, 'javascriptreact');
     }
  }
}
```